# Adicionar 1 minuto à hora

Tags: java, datetime

Estou com um problema a resolver um exercício. Pode ser fácil mas não estou a conseguir achar a solução correta.

Tenho a seguinte classe `Time`

```
public final class Time {
      private final int hours;
      private final int minutes;

      public Time(int h, int m) {hours = h; minutes = m;}

      public static final Time MIDNIGHT = new Time(0,0);

      public int getHours() {return hours;}

      public int getMinutes() {return minutes;}

      public Time tick() {
           return null;
      }
}
```

Tenho de definir o método `tick()` que deverá devolver um novo objeto de tipo `Time` correspondente à adição de um minuto sobre a hora representada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como no seu código tem a constante `MIDNIGHT`, estou assumindo que a classe `Time` representa **as horas do dia**.

Portanto, simplesmente somar 1 aos minutos pode trazer valores inválidos quando você tiver um `Time` que representa 15:59, por exemplo. Ao simplesmente somar 1 aos minutos, você acabará com o valor correspondente a 15:60 (e depois 15:61, 15:62, e assim por diante), quando o correto seria ter o valor 16:00 (e depois 16:01, 16:02, etc).

Por isso você deve somar 1 aos minutos e ajustar o valor, caso ele seja 60. Para isso usamos o operador `%`, que retorna o resto da divisão. Para garantir que o próximo minuto esteja entre 0 e 59, você pode fazer `(this.minutes + 1) % 60`.

Em seguida, se o valor dos minutos for zero, o valor das horas deve ser ajustado para a próxima hora. Estou assumindo que as horas também não podem ultrapassar os valores válidos, e que depois das 23:59, o próximo valor é 00:00. Sendo assim, eu também uso o operador `%`, mas agora com o valor 24 (garantindo que as horas tenham valores entre 0 e 23).

Sendo assim, o método `tick()` fica assim:

```
public Time tick() {
    int proximaHora = this.hours;
    int proximoMinuto = (this.minutes + 1) % 60;

    // se o próximo minuto é zero, deve ir para a próxima hora
    if (proximoMinuto == 0) {
        proximaHora = (proximaHora + 1) % 24;
    }
    return new Time(proximaHora, proximoMinuto);
}
```

Além disso, seria interessante o construtor validar os valores recebidos, para evitar que você crie horas inválidas como 99:99, por exemplo. Caso os valores sejam inválidos, você pode lançar um `IllegalArgumentException` (que é a exceção nativa que serve para indicar que um parâmetro inválido foi passado):

```
public Time(int h, int m) {
    if (h < 0 || h > 24) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Valor inválido para as horas: " + h);
    }
    if (m < 0 || m > 59) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Valor inválido para os minutos: " + m);
    }
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
}
```

Comment: tem toda a razão, obrigada!

Comment: `@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
     return this.hours.compareTo(o.hours)&&this.minutes.compareTo(o.minutes);
}` Sabe me dizer porque a implementação da interface Comparable dá-me erro no (o.hours) e (o.minutes) ?

Comment: Consegue me ajudar na duvida em cima ?

Comment: @StinRose Nesse caso, sugiro que você faça outra pergunta, para não misturar os assuntos. Mas talvez isso te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150446/compareto-with-primitives-integer-int

Comment: @StinRose A ideia de `a.compareTo(b)` é retornar -1 se a for menor que b, 0 se forem iguais e 1 se a for maior que b. O método retorna um número e vc está usando como um `boolean`, por isso não está funcionando

Comment: Assim ja estaria correto: `public int compareTo(Time o) {
  if(this.hours < o.hours && this.minutes < o.minutes) {return -1;}
  if(this.hours > o.hours && this.minutes > o.minutes) {return 1;}
  return 0;
 }`

Comment: Basta pensar como vc compara dois horários. Vc só precisa comparar os minutos se a hora for igual. Se as horas são diferentes, nem precisa comparar os minutos

Comment: Na verdade, não precisa retornar exatamente -1 e 1, pode ser qualquer número negativo ou positivo. Então fica algo como `if (this.hours == o.hours) { return this.minutes - o.minutes; } return this.hours - o.hours;` (se as horas forem iguais, compara os minutos; senão compara só as horas)

Comment: Ah, acho que ja percebi, então só caso as horas fores iguais `if(this.hours == o.hours)`, eu comparo os minutos `if(this.minutes < o.minutes) {return -1;}
if(this.minutes > o.minutes) {return 1;}`e no fim se forem todos iguais é que retorna 0

Comment: ah certo, ja percebi! pensei que tinha de retornar o -1 e 1

Comment: -1 e 1 costuma ser um "padrão" muito usado, mas a documentação diz que qualquer número negativo ou positivo serve: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)

Comment: já percebo, obrigada!